# How to add ant build properties in jenkinsfile

Tags: ant, jenkins-pipeline, salesforce

I am trying to create a `jenkinsfile` using ant script to build a `salesforce` project. I need to provide some build properties to execute the `ant` script.

**Here is my `jenkinsfile`:**

```
pipeline{
    agent any   
    environment{
    def antVersion ='Ant 1.9.16'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Checkout'){
            steps{
            git credentialsId: '******', url: 'https://********/test_repo.git', branch: 'develop'
            }
        }
        stage('Execute Ant Script'){
     steps{
 withEnv ([
              ["ANT_HOME=${tool antVersion}"],["readFile('./abc.txt').split('\n') as List"]
            ])
 {
 sh 'ant compile'
 }
           }
        }
    }
     post { 
        always { 
            cleanWs()
        } 
 } 
}
```

**Jenkins build fails with below error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EnvStep.overrides expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
 Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {overrides=[[ANT_HOME=C:\Users\********\Documents\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9.16-bin], [readFile('./abc.txt').split('
') as List]]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EnvStep
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:302)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Can anyone respond please, it is urgent.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Secondly, please format your code with code fences to make the code readable. Goodluck 